# Use collected digits from Call as a parameters of a Twilio Function or Value of Environment Variable

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Brand new to Twilio.

I've implemented the [Build Voice Mail with SMS and Email Notifications Using Twilio Studio, Functions, and SendGrid](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-serverless-voice-mail-sms-email-forwarding) tutorial. This tutorial relies on an Environment Variable named `TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS` to hold a static email address that is used in the `sgMail.send(msg)` command. I'd like to be able to variably set the value of `TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS` based on digits collected by a `Gather Input On Call` Widget.

I'm currently using the output of "user pressed keys" as two Variables. For one of them, I'm running a basic If/Else to convert the Digit to a String. This string is used in a `Say\Play` Widget in the next step.

```
{%- if flow.variables.department_id == '1' -%}
Dept1
{%- elsif flow.variables.department_id == '2' -%} 
Dept2 
{%- elsif flow.variables.department_id == '3' -%} 
Dept3
{%- endif -%}
```

I'd like to set the desired email address in the same manner.

That If/Else could just as easily end up as
If department_id == 1 then 'dept1@domain.com'...

Do I need to use that Environment Variable in this case? Could I just compute the correct email address in Studio and pass that as part of the Event when calling the Function?

The tutorial is great, and fit the use case. I feel like I'm missing some foundational knowledge though.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely control the email that the recording transcription is sent to.

You have set a Transcription Callback URL in the Record Coicemail widget in your Studio Flow. That causes Twilio to make a request to your Function when the transcription is complete. The request includes [all of the parameters listed in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-transcribecallback-parameters).

In order to choose an email address as part of the Studio Flow and then pass it on to the Function you will need to:

- Make the email address choice with the Gather widget before making the recording
- Set the email address or identifier as a variable in the Flow, as you described
- Pass the email address or identifier to the Function as a URL parameter.

So, if your Function URL is `https://ilovetwiliofunctions-1985.twil.io/fowardVMViaEmail`.

Then, using your variable, you can update it to: `https://ilovetwiliofunctions-1985.twil.io/fowardVMViaEmail?email={{flow.variables.email}}`.

You will then be able to read the email from the `event` object in the Function as `event.email` and use it in place of the environment variable.

Comment: Thank you So Much! That's just the nudge I needed.

Comment: Awesome! If this did help, please do mark the answer as correct so that others can see it was helpful too. Thanks!